# Why does $post not work but $ajax works on the asp.net web api controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I interested in knowing why does the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request work but  the [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) returns just an empty array on the controller.

controller

```
[Route("api/actuary/{actuaryId:long}/documents/")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> uploadCourseTrainingProofAsync(List<CourseModel> courseAttended)
{
    //code .....
}
```

This request works

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(courseAttended),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
})
```

But this one doesn't work, the courseAttended array is empty at the controller.

```
$.post(url, JSON.stringify(courseAttended), function (response) {
    console.log(response)
},"json")
```

Comment: Did you try to see the difference in your browser's Developer Tools Network panel?

Comment: are you getting any error in console and why you are passing 'json' at the end of the function call? i think it does not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post()` use the default `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` but you are using `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` with stringified data in your `$.ajax()` method.

If you were to use `$.post()` you would need to generate the data with collection indexers to match your `List<CourseModel>` parameter, for example

```
var data =  { [0].SomeProperty: SomeValue, [0].AnotherProperty: AnotherValue, [1].SomeProperty: SomeValue, .... };
$.post(url, data , function (response) {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to stringify your object in $.post

```
 $.post(url, courseAttended, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },"json")
```